Retrieving USD Value of Transferred ERC-20 Tokens via Etherscan API
I'm working on a project where I need to retrieve the USD value of ERC-20 tokens transferred in a specific transaction using the Etherscan API. For example, in the "ERC-20 Tokens Transferred" section on the Etherscan transaction details page, I can see values like "$231,221.00" for tokens.

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress={contract_address}&page=1&offset=10000&sort=asc&apikey={api_key}

However, this endpoint only provides the amount of tokens transferred, not the USD value.Does anyone know if it's possible to retrieve this USD value directly through the Etherscan API (either the free version or the PRO version)? If so, which endpoint should I be using, and are there any specific parameters I need to include?
Thanks in advance.

you cannot fetch the USD price of ERC-20 from the Etherscan API. To fetch the current or historical price in USD for an ERC-20 token you need to implement external APIs like Coingecko, or another price feed service. Let's look at coingecko to explain the concept:
coingecko example
// endpoint to get USD price
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/token_price/ethereum?contract_addresses={contract_address}&vs_currencies=usd

example with the USDT contract address:
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/token_price/ethereum?contract_addresses=0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7&vs_currencies=usd
// link above returns USDT token price in USD
{
  "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7": {
    "usd": :0.999007
  }
}

example to calculate value of transferred tokens
const tokenAmount = 1000000;
const tokenDecimal = 6;
const tokenPrice = 1.00;

const usdValue = (tokenAmount / 10**tokenDecimal) * tokenPrice;
console.log(usdValue);

You can write a script that includes all these steps, 1) retrieve the token transfer data, fetch current price of the token from a third-party API, 3) calculate USD value based on token amount.
There are many third-party providers which provide this data, so just pick one that fits you.
